# What is the difference between "In many ways" and "In many means"

Tags: usage

Can "in many means" be used at all? Like here, for example:

> Tea and Ceylon are synonymous in many means

Or is it better to use "in many ways" in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Means" is **not** right in this context.

I think the source of your confusion is that "ways and means" are often mentioned together, but they mean different things, otherwise it would be pointless saying both together!

- A *way* is a *possible* method, style or manner
- A *means* is an *available resource*

For example, driving and walking are two different *ways* of getting somewhere, but if you own a car then you have a *means* of transportation.

In the context of your example, a "way" means *a particular aspect of something*.

Your sentence should read:

> Tea and Ceylon are synonymous in many ways.